# Trying to understand why Cocotron isn't creating Framework DLLs

Tags: cocotron

I'm attempting to use Cocotron to build the Foundation framework. GCC 4.3.1 for Windows compiled fine, and it's creating valid Windows executable files, which I confirmed by making a "Hello, world" executable.

So what I don't understand is why, with Xcode 5.0.2, when I use either xcodebuild or build the Foundation project within Xcode itself, it isn't creating dll files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, it seems that as of Xcode 5, Apple no longer supports any compilers that are not derived from clang. To fix this issue, I had to copy the pbcomspec files from `/Library/Application Support/Shared/Xcode/Specifications` to `~/Library/Application Support/Shared/Xcode/Specifications` and edit the file that declares that the compiler is based on llvm-gcc to declare that it's based on `com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0`. Then it should at least *try* to build.

Comment: Additionally I had to install this [Cocotron Xcode 5 plugin](https://github.com/forensix/Cocotron-Xcode-5-Plugin) (make sure to edit its Info.plist to add `DVTPlugInCompatibilityUUIDs` as described in [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/forensix/Cocotron-Xcode-5-Plugin/issues/1)), restart Xcode to load the plugin, and edit the Cocotron Xcode projects as described in the Readme of [this Cocotron branch](https://github.com/forensix/Cocotron-Xcode-5).

Answer (score 0):

I try to use [hpc gcc](http://hpc.sourceforge.net/) instead clang and get same results.  I found that cocotron needs additional libraries zlib, libjpeg and libpng and in xcode 4.x build failed without they, but in xcode 5.x its only warnings and build marks as success. I didn't try fix it because we began use virtual machine with xcode 3.2, but maybe it is cause that libraries are not created

BTW I use [this post](http://lacquer.fi/pauli/blog/2012/02/win-win-with-cocotron-part-1/) and [this plugin](https://github.com/forensix/Cocotron-Xcode-5-Plugin)